# Create different users in Ruby with iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm new in Ruby. I want to create different users in ruby using iteration.

```
def createuser(*args)
      obj = H['userClass']
      obj.login                 = H['login']
      obj.password              = a.password = @default_passwd
      obj.email                 = 'test@example.com'
      obj.role                  = MasterUser::ROLE_MASTER_USER
end
```

For example I want to call this method and send these arguments:

```
H = Hash["userClass" => MasterUser.new, "login" => admin]
createuser(H)
```

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Please note that in ruby, variable starting with a capital are considered constants. Not that that matters very much, as constants aren't really that contstant in ruby, so you can just use them as variables, but it will produce warnings if you try to reassign them. And it is not very idiomatic. Local variables normally are written in lower (snake) case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version. It should bring you closer to your goal, while still being recognizable :

```
def create_user(parameters)
  klass         = parameters['user_class']
  user          = klass.new
  user.login    = parameters['login']
  user.password = @default_passwd
  user.email    = 'test@example.com'
  user.role     = klass::ROLE_MASTER_USER
  user
end

user_params = {"user_class" => MasterUser, "login" => 'admin'}
new_user = create_user(user_params)
```

Comment: Do you mean for the parameter? It's less a problem for a string than for a method or class, IMHO. Still, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
class UserFactory
  attr_accessor :user
  def initialize(klass)
    @user = klass.new
  end
  def create(params = {})
    user.login = params.fetch :login
    user.password = params.fetch :password, 'default_password'
    user.email = params.fetch :email
    # user.role should just be initialised on the klass.new call, no need to do that here
    # etc...
  end
end

class MasterUser
  ROLE = 'master_role'
  attr_accessor :login, :password, :email, :role
  def initialize
    self.role = ROLE
  end
end
```

which you would call like:

```
UserFactory.new(MasterUser).create(login: 'george', password: 'secret', email: 'me@george.com')
```

The reason I'd use `params.fetch :login`, instead of just reading it, is that in Ruby accessing a hash by a key that it doesn't have returns `nil`, while trying to `fetch` it will throw an error. 
For example:

```
a = {}
a[:foo] #=> nil
a.fetch :foo #=> throw a KeyError
```

So that is a way of enforcing that the argument hash has the right keys.